# Space above and below text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a container that I need to have exactly `16dp` of padding on all sides.

Inside the container is a `TextView`, but I measured the space from the top of the text to the top of the container and it comes out to `18dp` (same on the bottom).

It appears that the text adds space above and below. How does Google suggest we deal with this issue (what's the guideline)?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGrfw.png

The blue is the area of the `TextView`. As you can see, there's extra space above and below the text.

How can I remove the space around the text?

Comment: A short hack is to use "android:layout_marginTop="-2"" in textview

Comment: Can you please post the XML code?

Comment: @Shahzeb Doesn't the value depend on text size though? For example, text with font size `100dp` won't have `2dp` of space above it.

Comment: I think No. you should check this

Comment: @Shahzeb Just checked. Larger text has more space above and below it.

Comment: Alright, have you checked "android:layout_margin="0""?

Comment: That's margin around the text, not for removing the space above and below the text.

Comment: Have you try to check TextView Line Spacing : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingExtra

Comment: That would affect the spacing between lines, when I only want to remove the spacing above the top line and below the bottom line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `android:includeFontPadding="false"` to see if it helps. It will help a little bit, but there's no way of reducing the TextView dimensions to the exact pixel-perfect text size.

The only alternative, which may or may not give better results, is to cheat a bit and hard-wire the dimensions to match the text size, e.g. "24sp" instead of "wrap_content" for the height.